# Pandas - Nice Alternative instead of 'lookup'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for an alternative for 'lookup' function in pandas dataframe.

I've seen several examples including [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup), but I can't apply this to on my own.

I have 2 DataFrames described as below.

A

```
| name |
| ---- |
|foo   |
|bar   |
|hello |
|world |
```

B

```
|keyword|frequency|
| ----- |---------|
|hello  | 3       |
|foo    | 10      |
```

And I wanna add a new column on `A` dataframe like this
A

```
| name |frequency|
| ---- |---------|
|foo   |10       |
|bar   |0        |
|hello |3        |
|world |0        |
```

As you see, if a value of `A` dataframe's `name` column is in `B` dataframe's `keyword` column, add frequency from the same row.

If it doesn't exist, just add `0`.

I can achieve this with for-loop, but this is not looks good and also slow.

Is there any elegant and efficient way to do this ?
(I hope to utilize vectorization of pands, if possible)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need add one or multiple columns use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `rename` and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'keyword': 'name'}), how='left').fillna(0)
print (df)
    name  frequency
0    foo       10.0
1    bar        0.0
2  hello        3.0
3  world        0.0
```

Or if need add only one column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['frequency'] = (df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('keyword')['frequency'])
                               .fillna(0, downcast='int'))
print (df1)
    name  frequency
0    foo         10
1    bar          0
2  hello          3
3  world          0
```